# Getting canvas height and width from model and creating canvas with those dimensions

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails

So in my mind this should be pretty simply but I cannot seem to get this right. When creating a whiteboard, the user inputs two numbers, height and width. I'm trying to apply these given numbers to the canvas object but am struggling. Here's my code:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div id=thecanvas>
    <canvas id="board" width="<%= @whiteboard.canvas_width %>" 
                       height="<%= @whiteboard.canvas_height %>">
    </canvas>
</div>
```

Rails expects `<%= %>` tags for Ruby code in a template file.